# Метод Рунге-Кутта 4-го порядка для CДУ C#

Tags: c#, математика, численные-методы

Нужно решить систему из двух дифференциальных уравнений методом Рунге-Кутты 4-го порядка с коррекцией шага по правилу Рунге.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как мне нужно корректировать шаг,то я хотела написать метод rk4,как и в случае с одним уравнением,но загвоздка в том,что я не совсем понимаю что он должен возвращать?Ведь метод может вернуть только одно значение.А для системы из двух уравнений нужно вернуть два значения. В моём случае Y и Z.
Помогите разобраться что я не так делаю.Или же есть способ реализации проще,учитывая оценку по Рунге.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Название конечно пугает, но чтобы вернуть 2 значения из какой-то функции можно сделать структуру, в которой есть эти 2 значения и возвращать её, например.

Comment: Я об этом думала,но тогда для оценки локальной погрешности нужно будет прописать сложение,вычитание и другие операции для этой структуры.Возможно есть способ проще.Либо я что-то не до конца понимаю в самом методе

Comment: свяжите корни уравнения какой-то однозначной функцией, ну как бы "зашифруйте" в одном. Например  в первую цифру запишите количество знаков до запятой, потом количество знаков после запятой и ещё количество знаков в 2 числе до запятой(на каждый пункт по 2 знака), дальше 1 число, дальше 2 число. Всё это в одном большом числе(я даже не знаю имеете ли вы доступ к методу или нет). Потом расшифруйте обратно и получите 2 ответа в одном числе

Comment: Вообще результатом численных расчетов будут два массива и третий это x с шагом.

Comment: Пробую способ через класс.Всё упирается в то,что не удаётся неявно преобразовать тип класса в тип double в куске кода с оценкой локальной погрешности  `if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
            {

                V = rk4(x, u, h); // текущее значение функции
                Vn1 = rk4(x, u, h / 2); //Vn+1/2
                V_2i = rk4(x + h / 2, Vn1, h / 2); //V c крышкой
                S = 16 * (V_2i - V) / 15.0; //оценка локальной погрешности`